# How to use Amazon RDS in Spring MVC Application

Tags: spring-mvc, amazon-rds

I want to use Amazon RDS read replica in my Spring MVC application.Currently my application is running on self hosted Mysql server.But Now I want to switch my application on Amazon RDS master ans read replica .What I need to do in my existing xml configuration file.For use amazon RDS read replica. Currently I am using MYbatis ORM for query.

My XML configuration is this

```
<!-- Declare a datasource that has pooling capabilities -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" p:driverClass="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:jdbcUrl="${jdbc.url}" p:user="${jdbc.username}"       p:password="${jdbc.password}"
    p:acquireIncrement="10" p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="60"    p:maxPoolSize="10"
    p:maxStatements="50" p:minPoolSize="1" />

<!-- Declare a transaction manager -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" />
```

Comment: you don't need anything special. Just set url and other config in your file. RDS nothing but a mysql instance.

Comment: I want to use RDS read read replica feature . I am able use RDS single instance and my web application working fine.but My question is dis ..Is Amazon manage read replica for all read request or I need to  do some configuration inside my web application label...

Comment: read replica is a completely different instance from master. so yes you should define another connection to read replica server and use that for read only queries.